# php grouping in tables based on category

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Im currently sitting with the problem of grouping an array into html tables based on a item in the array called category.

I have the following code:

```
foreach ($this->items as $item) {
    $categories[] = $item->category;
}

<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <?php foreach ($this->items as $item) :?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->description; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->price; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But how do i tell it, that based on its category it needs to go into a table or create a table for that category?

end result for each separate category should look like:

[image]

**Adding a description:**

Think I fixed it.. I used this code:

```
foreach( $this->items as $item ){
if( !isset( $zones[ $item->zone ] ) )
$zone_items[ $item->zone] = array();
$zone_items[ $item->zone ][] = $item;

    $zones[$item->zone] = array(
        'zone' => $item->zone,
        'zone_description' => $item->zone_description,
        'items' => $zone_items[$item->zone]
    );

}


<?php foreach( $zones as $zone): ?>
    <?php echo $zone['zone']; ?><br />
    <?php echo $zone['zone_description']; ?>

    <?php foreach( $zone['items'] as $items ) :?>
        <?php echo $items->name; ?>
        <?php echo $items->description; ?>
        <?php echo $items->category; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and I get the name and description but no items.. Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: You can do that by adding nested loop inside your loop by catrgories

Comment: you have to build your array with multiple dimensions, category being the first dimension and then your items for each category in the next dimension. then you can use two loops to display categories and items in category

Comment: Guys... I'm not to great at programming... any resources/examples would be great...

Comment: I'm used to write html inside php by echoig, not everytime closing and calling php before and after html. Try it, then you will feel more space and you will get what you're missing. You just have to build new table structure in `foreach ($categories as $category)` play with <td> and <tr> tags and you will get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? I didn't test it so pardon any bugs but, you get the idea :) The table in my example is also screwy, umm... Will just take some fiddling to get it right from here ;P

```
$categories = array();
foreach( $this->items as $item )
{
    if( !isset( $categories[ $item->category ] ) ) $categories[ $item->category] = array();
    $categories[ $item->category ][] = $item;
}

<?php foreach( $categories as $category => $items ): ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="<?php echo count( $items ); ?>"><?php echo $category; ?></td>
            <?php foreach( $items as $item ) :?>
                <td><?php echo $item->description; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->price; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

To include a description for categories, you'll want to rework the array. Now, I don't know where your category descriptions are coming from, so I'll just show you how the array and output should look, and leave it up to you how to build it;

```
<?php
$categories = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Category Name',
        'description' => 'This is the category description',
        'items' => $itemsForThisCategory //you can still sort the items by category like I did above and then do "$itemsSortedByCategory[ 'Category Name' ]" here
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Another Category Name',
        'description' => 'This is the description for another category',
        'items' => $itemsForAnotherCategory
    ),
    //etc... as many categories as you have
);
?>
```

Then the output would look like this;

```
<?php foreach( $categories as $category ): ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="<?php echo count( $category['items'] ); ?>">
                <?php echo $category['name']; ?><br />
                <?php echo $category['description']; ?>
            </td>
            <?php foreach( $category['items'] as $item ) :?>
                <td><?php echo $item->description; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->price; ?></td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Hey just a question, lets say i needed to add another thing called category description with the category name... how would i do this?

Comment: Woops, can't put code down here. I will edit my answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = [];

foreach( $this->items as $item )
{
    $categories[$item->category][] = $item;
}
```

Now you should have an associative `$categories` array, with each index being a category, and containing items of that category. Now you would just loop through that with a foreach, output the `$category` index, and output the objects contained within.